# regular expression for password

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords

I need help coming up with a regular expression for javascript which has to verify a password. 
 
The password (8 characters long, at least one non-letter character) 
it would also be useful to make sure the user does not have spaces at the  beginning or end

Comment: Before asking, did you do a search for "Javascript password validation"? (This question gets asked a lot and there are many good answers.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a pattern that will match what you asked for

`pattern = /^(?=.*[^a-z])\S.{6}\S$/i;`

Answer (score 0):

Depends how 'complicated' you want to get but I find either if the following useful:

```
/*
    No more than 4 same characters
    - One digit
    - One uppercase
    - One lowercse
    - One 'punctuation' mark
    - between 8 and 20 characters
*/                                  
re = /^(?!.*(.)\1{4})((?=.*[\d])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[^\w\d\s])).{8,20}$/;

/*
    - One Digit
    - One lower case
    - One upper case
    - Maximum 2 repeating char
    - between 6 and 20 characters
*/                                  
re = /^(?!.*(.)\1{2})((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)).{6,20}$/;
```

These are not my regexp's as I found them on the web but can't remember where.